# Feed large csv in Python TFLearn

Tags: python, large-files, tflearn

I have searched the internet for an answer to this, but I cannot seem to find it!

I have a large csv file (about 14gb, and will be using even larger files at a later stage) that I would like to train a model on with TFLearn.  I have a file prep function that will test the data and remove all unwanted fields.  It will also create two files (one for training and one for predicting:

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import load_csv

train_file, test_file = prep('data/large.csv', remove=[0, 1], test=.2)

data, labels = load_csv(train_file, has_header=False, n_classes=2)

model.fit(data, labels, batch_size=20, validation_set=.1, n_epoch=20)
```

The problem is the load_csv - where I run into memory issues.  The prep section reads the large.csv file in chunks and appends it to the train_file, so memory is not an issue here.  I also tried to convert the large.csv into H5 format and saving in batches, in order to retrieve the data in batches (in a loop):

```
with h5py.File('large.h5, 'a') as hf:
    hf.create_dataset('batch%d' % (n_batch), data=chunk)
```

And during training:

```
for n in number_of_batches:
    with open h5py.File('large.h5','r') as hf:
        b = hf['batch%d' % (n)][:]
        # Then I have some code to write the small batch to small.csv.
        data, labels = load_csv('small.csv', ...)
        model.fit(data, labels, ...)
```

The latter option works with regards to memory, but I it does not do well on training the model (it is training at 1000 rows per loop).

Should I use the TensorFlow placeholders?  I am not sure how to implement them with TFLearn.  TFLearn also has an ImagePreloader, but I do not have images for classification.  My data is in a csv with 1000+ columns (all of equal length).

Comment: Can't you cut your file in smaller part, then train on each smaller, more manageable part? I know this isn't totally what you asked (on if you should use tensorflow placeholders) but couldn't it work on your problem?

Comment: Thank Eric. I can do that. Should I load the model weights from the last best checkpoint between training each smaller file? I am thinking of placing this in a loop. I would have thought that it would be better to train each epoch on all available records.

Comment: I think it could work, sorry I never tried that (my excel file while having lot of data don't have the problem of being too big). My best advice would be to try both and see which give you the better results (accuracy, loss and prediction wise). Though from what I've seen making research on it people do load the model and the weights from last training but once again I can't tell you for sure that it will give the best results. Trial and error is still the best way to discover that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try!

Comment: If it work tell me, either I post an answer or you do and accept it. People later could have this problem, having an answered question on this subject may help them to find a solution.

Comment: @EricGodard. Did you ever get to solve this please? Your contribution will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @wernerfeuer. Did you ever get to solve this please? Your contribution will be very much appreciated.